# Como utilizar funções de uma classe em outra?

Tags: php, funções, classes

Em um projeto estava usando uma `class` para definir funções para todo o projeto, e como o projeto está crescendo surgiu a necessidade da criação de um novo arquivo com novas `class` e `function`.

Neste caso preciso consumir a `class` que faz a conexão com banco do no primeiro arquivo. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Mostre melhor o problema

Comment: O modo mais simples de fazer, é no segundo arquivo fazer um `include/require` do arquivo de conexão e criar um objeto da classe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o [@rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray) disse, no seu novo arquivo utilize os métodos mencionados:

`NovaClass.php`:

```
require 'caminho/do/arquivo/de/conexao/arquivo.php'
require 'caminho/do/arquivo/de/funções/arquivo.php'

class NovaClass {

}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente para o objetivo atual.

Comment: Acrescentaria essa opção também em meus estudos acabei me deparando com a questão da herança que também ajuda na minha dúvida inicial. [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode usar include/include_once/require/require_once no arquivo em que irá consumir.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.require-once.php

Para utilizar metodos de uma classe, dentro de metodos de outra classe, basta vc instanciar a classe desejada e fazer o uso normal dela.